# Can two endorsing peers in hyperledger Fabirc sync themselves to each other after a network communication loss?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, decentralized-applications

I want two know that if two peers are in a same organization and lets assume they are 1 km apart connected through wifi. Now both are endorsing peers and saves transactions on themselves.
so what if every peer gets disconnected from the internet and cant communicate with each other.
Will they both crash ?

I expect that they will work on there own. Commits transactions to the ledger. Once the network is established between them. They will sync there transactions and start working back again.

Answer (score 0):

You are partially correct in that Peers will "catch up" if they are offline for a period, however it is more complex than that.  In most real world scenarios more than 1 peer is required for endorsement so if peers are offline they may cause problems with transaction completion.

Peers simulate transactions, but do not commit until after endorsement, and after Ordering, so a peer in isolation cannot execute a transaction.

There is a good document in the Fabric docs that covers [the transaction flow](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orderer/ordering_service.html).

Comment: Okay Imagine this. There are 100 Organizations and every one of them have an orderer connected to it and have about 10 peers. 5 endorsing peers. Now 1 of these 100 organizations looses communication with the remaining 99 organization and there peers. Can this organization with its endorsing peers and orderer still handling transactions? Keeping in mind that the remaining 99 Orgs are working together as they are still connected. 
SO now that the internet is back. The 99 org peers have there ledger state and this 1 orgs peers have there state. Can they sync everything up ?
**Note: Same ledge**